# joomla 2.5 frontend login (with admin name/pass) works, but backend login fails

Tags: authentication, joomla2.5, administration

Ok I have been on this all day. It just started out of nowhere. I can log into my site, with the admin name and password from the front end no problem. But the backend is the issue.
I have done the configuration.php session_handler tip (none, file and database)
I have deleted all browser history. i even installed a fresh browser and tried that after wiping database sessions. Now i am stuck on

"You do not have access to the administrator section of this site."
or
"Your session has expired. Please log in again."
or
"Invalid security token refresh your browser."

1) configuration.php -> $session_handler = 'database';
2) Viewing Levels are correct -> 6,Super Users, Developer,0,[9,8]
3) Userid and password are correct.
4) user_usergroup_map is correct -> 72,9
5) I do not have the JSecure or whatever that was installed

HELP!? A wipe is not possible, this is a prototype joomla with alot of work done but the core authentication has never been edited or modified, however the rest article, links, etc have been replaced by integrated K2, JoomlaWorks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your user doesn't have the correct permissions to log in to the back end of the site.

Check the #__users table for the group id of the user and then check the usergroups and user_usergroup_map tables to make sure the user has admin permissions.